# Web scraping yahoo finance with selenium

Tags: selenium

It's driving me nuts but I really don't find the answer to my problem. I have done some coding with python and selenium to scrape the yahoo finance news from Daimler. But it simply doesn't work. I always get the following message in pycharm:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

But I am quite sure that the selector chosen is the only appropriate one to chose.. Here my coding:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DAI.DE?p=DAI.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch'


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/CFDS/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)


driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


articles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('js-stream-content Pos(r)')


for article in articles:
    source = article.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="quoteNewsStream-0-Stream"]/ul/li[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
    title = article.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quoteNewsStream-0-Stream"]/ul/li[5]/div/div/div[2]/h3/a').text
    text = article.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quoteNewsStream-0-Stream"]/ul/li[5]/div/div/div[2]/p').text
    date = article.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="quoteNewsStream-0-Stream"]/ul/li[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[2]').text

    print(source,title,text,date)
```

What's wrong. Really appreciate some help!

Thx a lot

---

Maybe it is useful to see the whole error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Startklar/PycharmProjects/test/venv/Selenium Test.py", line 15, in <module>
    articles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.js-stream-content Pos(r)')
  File "C:\Users\Startklar\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 614, in find_elements_by_css_selector
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\Startklar\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\Startklar\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Startklar\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

---

that's the latest code by the way

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DAI.DE?p=DAI.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch'


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/CFDS/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)


driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.js-stream-content")))


for article in articles:
    try:
         source = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
         title = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/h3/a').text
         text = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/p').text
         date = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
         print(source,title,text,date+'/n')
    except:
        print("")
```

Comment: thx, but I am getting the same error message, with or without the "."

Answer (score 1):

Your xpaths and article selector was off.

```
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.js-stream-content")))

for article in articles:
    try:
        source = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/div/span[1]').text
        title = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/h3/a').text
        text = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[2]/p').text
        date = article.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[1]/div/span[2]').text
        print(source,title,text,date+'/n')
    except:
        print("")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi, I've modified the code as written by you, but I am still getting the same error message...

Comment: Odd I'm getting correct values maybe add a wait to articles.

Comment: We have different css selectors rn also yours is wrong. Compound classes need a . between them.

Comment: Thx arundeep chohan, I looks better, but now he claims that "WebDriverWait" is not defined... Sorry for all these questions I am an absolute beginner..

Comment: It's ok. Just import the appropriate items.

Comment: ok that looks much better now. No more error messages. But I am not really satisfied with the result. I do get just one news but it shows me this one three times. How did you get the commands for source for example? Did you copy selector or xpath or something else?

Comment: Some of the tags for xpath are off. In certain cases you won't have the same xpath for all tags.

Comment: You can actually print article.text in the for loop to see what you are working with.

Comment: sounds like the list/DOM is still being updated when you grab the array of webelement references.  The expected condition of "presence_of_all_elements_located" only waits until at least one item is there.  You can either hard-code a sleep, or catch Stale Element exceptions to re-grab the webelement reference array.

Comment: how can I see, if some of the xpath's are off?

Comment: @pcalkins thx for your comment. You mean I would need an additional sleep beside the one for WebDriverWait? Where and how is that sleep to place?

Comment: exactly... the expected condition only waits until at least 1 item is there... depending on how the DOM is populated the JS could still be adding items, which messes with your references.  So add a sleep before getting the array of element references.  (I don't know python, so not sure exactly how you'd do that.)  Better is to functionize and catch Stale Element exceptions... run function that gets the elements if caught.

Comment: ok, what means DOM? JS stands for Java Script I guess. If I need to get a sleep before the array of elements, couldn't I just increase the 30 let's say to 100? By doing so I am still getting the same result. Do I have to go higher with the figure or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: It is also very strange that I get an text which is not on the site (just realized that) and I only get the text, not the other requested information such as source, date or title...